# Configurable Product Missing After Reindexing

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, reindex, magento-2.1.3, magento-2.1.4

I have imported products using data migration tool from M1 to M2. But some products does not show on frontend. When I save the product manually it appears on frontend but after reindexing it again vanishes. I am not getting what could be the reason for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Mind the changes that occur in 'cataloginventory_stock_status' table after reindexing. In my case, Reindexing added a row like - 1-0-2(product_id-website_id-stock_id) while i had already a row like 1-1-2(product_id-website_id-stock_id). 
So, I fired query - Delete from 'cataloginventory_stock_status' where website='0' and stock_id=2`. This worked in mine case. 
Make suitable changes and its going to work. Always take backup before any changes.

This is not a good solution but its all i got.